# How to create some test data using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF 4 and MVC in C#,

When my application loads, I would like load create some entities to be added to my database, so where is the best place to add thsi functionality using EF? `Global.asax` on Start application?

What is a reasonable name convention for the class... BootStrap?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using DbContext or ObjectContext? Do you want to create that entities each time the application starts or only the first time? Do you have existing database or is the database created during the first startup?

Comment: Good question Im using DbContext, I would like create the entities the first time the app run, the DB allready exist, I just need insert some data when the app start for testing thansk for your help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have existing database you should not include the initialization into your application. The only way how to make this work in existing database is to execute some initialization in `Application_Start`. The initialization must check existence of every entity you want to insert and insert data only if the entity is not present. Because your database already exists, the initialization logic will have to run every time you restart the application. To avoid this you would also need some flag in the database to mark that initialization was already done (one of inserted entity can be considered as a "flag" but only if the application cannot remove this entity).

EF normally seeds data only when creating database or after database migration.

Edit: If you are creating test data on your test database you should be happy with database recreation each time your model changes (or with migrations) and custom database initializer to seed your data.